# "Occasionally, I receive requests that does not meet our requirements"

Tags: grammar

"Occasionally, I receive requests that does not meet our requirements" - "does not" or "do not" should be used in this context?

Comment: The relative pronoun 'that' does not imply any quantity, but its antecedent 'requests' is a plural noun, which governs agreement of the verb 'do', so "do not"  is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"do not" is correct.  It must agree with "requests."  You can test it by saying "the requests do not meet our requirements."